# Efficient computation of nth mixed partial derivative of factorized multivariate polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, polynomials, partial-derivative, computational-complexity

I have a large multivariate polynomial of $n$ variables expressed as a product of terms:
$$P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = T_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \times \dots \times T_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ .$$

The maximum degree of any $x_i$ in a given term is one, and the number of terms where any $x_i$ appears is at most two. The problem is just the number of variables/terms, which can be very large.

I would like to know if there would exist an efficient (polynomial-time) way to evaluate the following partial derivative at a given point:

$$\frac{\partial^n P}{\partial x_1\dots\partial x_n} \ \text{?}$$

I've tried automatic differentiation with e.g. Torch but it doesn't scale up so well. The coefficients of the polynomial are complex numbers.

This answer asks a similar question for an arbitrary function: [Numerical computation of the $n^{\mathrm {th}}$ derivative of a multivariate function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663539/numerical-computation-of-the-n-mathrm-th-derivative-of-a-multivariate-fun) but I haven't found anything useful in the only answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found elements of answer in the following papers:

[Multivariate Polynomial Integration and Derivative Are Polynomial
Time Inapproximable Unless P=NP∗](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2377), Bin Fu

[Approximating Multilinear Monomial Coefficients
and Maximum Multilinear Monomials in
Multivariate Polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2678.pdf), Zhixiang Chen, Bin Fu

[On testing monomials in multivariate polynomials](https://%20https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271538/1-s2.0-S0304397513X00271/1-s2.0-S0304397512003106/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIDd2I6dgIpx5SgRs50X1KOoNU6f8c%2Fh04ZSY9YiCVbVQAiARF2mjdm15rMTg5Zg5Yu74EbAs7wVRPesROHAHM4ShpSq8BQi%2B%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM7ZPR8HdyZ9m0dBTnKpAFSwb2wzbPLp%2FxxdVC8%2Bhkeix6wRdZAYuJ0tKeQOqcFICh7kTsCt0i3yj5RhBdBja0yWfgj%2FXTL4beV7V9D3%2BzVXLCLDsPqnQoQiD2SdIihyA6Y1maAfXOmA1wXgn%2BnW3eI%2FhzFIuE8Tp%2FjJtD%2BcDN%2BuODW9JcySjcQ9nzIrViVpksCvavTCQ1BVBaxMwotsPPeoCfU4hRLgZLR9MEAah%2F0GbS87U1mI6L145PcDH%2BeJIurzk9LlzoPyhHCWi1QVp385%2FoPq2ntjZh5TgSl%2FSv1e%2FUTu6oK8dVozZSNIY3mjRXwqEPS76E2e3ivc7BpoRfYd6pVOBfYP7eLEm0UOWKZNFuLeUV9Cv3RNdfVuiiYmBr08g2MS0odSCD%2FoUll%2BgkfS06l%2BuRF2D7PA3l6HorVpCyjDXQhEavOZYdUlqcg%2BJj4E24T47YdaGgFUx3Xoj%2BSACxqmatWQtLSN%2FBoqSgj5dGjnKt4C7AqhPyFhUfoRrjH%2F6V0v6XoERe7f4hyHlOHlCnVvI46FRtoXLKdvinkhI51PSygkYPVYr3bSxkE%2FckQdnbuphr%2FhZvzTBju6Y62Ceh2PL24CRYanNeXatdOBSSMpBbD4yuFRUlQ06Hmy3FbI%2FPEdHm%2Fa2Oh8r7K0FOdJ62u6JEX5v%2FCWh%2Bz%2FjzT4gQRgL0rh03d1RZNrwyVs8yIljcsWBuzS1znIHQ30hgeMd5fxNJlKuFAy1RXrjZWYAaqEKRQ23NoNCUE%2BcOlP27NRntzEI%2BFN06XkLdpCtMho5Os259DbWwm0t8OPWJN5VrY%2FnzuLKMfQDqnDIEfFd4jncFJ0Q3ZRNtbpMBJkvtA4FvzuoSFFZQrw15ybKU2p7XRqfjFpugVwYaLSDyqT4wv9HEqQY6sgGXUixpO4At4YlMziAvWnai6Dk0lGdm2ZUQHk3BytH0JmeztjSMhtArMbDEGcId7JVrMVnqEsN9hlo48jSBtejCyTdxmDoktG%2BxMzf8xzLCpTZ0NqVstdLk3vMBujSHj0qegy%2BfxS1tJ4rsSlj9SDPI7Fx%2BRt4zQVcRkbzSUoBnfMMxrqdvn2HbUXwnvfoglnETbzF30jqwCmnj32StCAlXMtwgi9fSlI2dMONyMRl1XWe8&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231019T133651Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWEQZALHK%2F20231019%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=30ef65b3adbf27e64c23f696a2f497f83358035db7cc647005db233f016c1477&hash=77788f2c2aa1cc294bed6773a3eb645f98540b89e9ae3100649bf4840cc8b3be&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0304397512003106&tid=spdf-855e6f5c-334f-4406-b313-30842b497705&sid=2815be112384e344906a9f302016cf189e6dgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=140a5c545e5c51595c040f&rr=8189698da8b30bc0&cc=nl), Zhixiang Chen, Bin Fu, Yang Liu, Robert Schweller

This problem doesn't seem to have a polynomial-time solution.